# Chnging the float roud-up mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to change the round-up mode using the `_controlfp_s` function. Here is the code:

```
void precission(void) {
    unsigned int control_word;
    int err;
    float a = 10.0, b = 3.0;
    char MsgBuff[300];

    float result1, result2;

    err = _controlfp_s(&control_word, _RC_UP, _MCW_RC);
    if (err) {
        sprintf_s(MsgBuff, 300, "Error \n");
        OutputDebugStringA(MsgBuff);
    }

    result1 = a / b;

    sprintf_s(MsgBuff, 300, "float division : %.3f / %.3f = %.3f \n", a, b, a / b);
    OutputDebugStringA(MsgBuff);

    err = _controlfp_s(&control_word, _RC_DOWN, _MCW_RC);
    if (err) {
        sprintf_s(MsgBuff, 300, "Error \n");
        OutputDebugStringA(MsgBuff);
    }

    result2 = a / b;

    sprintf_s(MsgBuff, 300, "float division : %.3f / %.3f = %.3f \n", a, b, a / b);
    OutputDebugStringA(MsgBuff);
}
```

When i investigate the value of variables in debugger i get:
`3.33333349` for `result1` and `3.33333325` for `result2` respectively.

My question is why isn't it just `3.33333334` and `3.33333332` (where the `9` and `5` on the end respectively comes from?) and why is the precision 8 digits long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to the limited precision of a `float` data type.

There is no way to represent any value between `3.33333325` and `3.33333349` using a `float`, because the minimum "step" (*epsilon*) of a single-precision `float` is `0.000000119209`.

```
int main() {
    unsigned int control_word;
    float a = 10.0, b = 3.0;

    float result1, result2;
    unsigned x1, x2;

    printf("float epsilon = %.12f\n", std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon());

    _controlfp_s(&control_word, _RC_UP, _MCW_RC);

    result1 = a / b;
    memcpy(&x1, &result1, sizeof(x1));

    printf("float division : %.3f / %.3f = %.12f, hex %08lX \n", a, b, result1, x1);

    _controlfp_s(&control_word, _RC_DOWN, _MCW_RC);

    result2 = a / b;
    memcpy(&x2, &result2, sizeof(x2));

    printf("float division : %.3f / %.3f = %.12f, hex %08lX \n", a, b, result2, x2);
}
```

Output:

```
float epsilon = 0.000000119209
float division : 10.000 / 3.000 = 3.333333492279, hex 40555556
float division : 10.000 / 3.000 = 3.333333253860, hex 40555555
```

So the difference between two values is 1 lowest bit.

> why isn't it just `3.33333334` and `3.33333332` ?

This is because IEEE 754 encoding is a base-2 encoding, it can't represent those values exactly (link to [more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)).

Comment: So the epsilon == `0.000000119209` == `1` (just "one") in hex?

Comment: yes. epsilon is the lowest fraction bit of a float. Since `float` has [23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#/media/File:Float_example.svg) fraction bits, epsilon is pow(2,-23), or ~0.00000011920928955078125. This is not the smallest possible float, it just represents the *resolution* of around 6 decimal digits.

Comment: Can You be so nice and eplain me why do You copy the result1 and result2 to the locations? Why not just to display the value in hex directly:  printf("float division : %.3f / %.3f = %.12f, hex %08lX \n", a, b, result2, result2) without copying?

Comment: That is to avoid compiler warnings. MSVC issues a warning about an incompatible format string.

Comment: Another question. Looking from pure binary content of the memory celsl is the `result1` and `x1` (after copying as You written of course) the SAME? Bit by bit?

Comment: Yes, we're just printing the same float bits as hex.